# How can I make the element that became visible move next to the visible element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code I assume that the hidden select box appears underneath the the visible select box because the button has gotten the available space next to the visible select and as a result the select box once it becomes visible it "drops" bellow the visible select.
Am I right?
So how would I be able to "move" the button and place the second select next to the first select?

```
<html>  
<body>  
    <table>  
        <tr>
            <td id="t">  
                <div id="select1">  
                    <select>  
                        <option>  
                            John Smith    
                        </option>  
                        <option>  
                            Bill Johnson  
                        </option>  
                        <option>  
                            Mary Jones    
                        </option>  
                    </select>   
                </div>  
                <div id="select2" style="display:none">  
                    <select>  
                        <option>  
                            CA      
                        </option>  
                        <option>  
                            AZ     
                        </option>    
                        <option>    
                            NV      
                        </option>   
                    </select>   
                </div>
            </td>  
            <td><input type="submit" value="Press me!" onclick="doit()"/>  </td>
        </tr>  
</table>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function doit() {  
        document.getElementById("select2").style.display="block";  
    }   
</script>    
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo Is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uQJQe/).

`Div` tags are by default block element which means it would break the next element to next line so by applying inline property, you forced it to stay on same line.

`display:inline` is the property you need:

```
<html>  
 <body>  
    <table>  
        <tr>
            <td id="t">  
                <div id="select1" style="display:inline">  
                    <select>  
                        <option>  
                            John Smith    
                        </option>  
                        <option>  
                            Bill Johnson  
                        </option>  
                        <option>  
                            Mary Jones    
                        </option>  
                    </select>   
                </div>  
                <div id="select2"  style="display:none">  
                    <select>  
                        <option>  
                            CA      
                        </option>  
                        <option>  
                            AZ     
                        </option>    
                        <option>    
                            NV      
                        </option>   
                    </select>   
                </div>
            </td>  
            <td><input type="submit" value="Press me!" onclick="doit()"/>  </td>
        </tr>  
</table>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function doit() {  
        document.getElementById("select2").style.display="inline";  
    }   
</script>    
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: +1. This works. Would you elaborate a little on why it works?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just placing the 2nd select in a separate cell?

EG:

```
<table>  
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Select Header</th> <th>Button Header</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tr>
        <td id="t">  
            <div id="select1">  
                <select>  
                    <option>  
                        John Smith    
                    </option>  
                    <option>  
                        Bill Johnson  
                    </option>  
                    <option>  
                        Mary Jones    
                    </option>  
                </select>   
            </div> 
         </td>
         <td> 
            <div id="select2" style="display:none">  
                <select>  
                    <option>  
                        CA      
                    </option>  
                    <option>  
                        AZ     
                    </option>    
                    <option>    
                        NV      
                    </option>   
                </select>   
            </div>
        </td>  
        <td><input type="submit" value="Press me!" onclick="doit()"/>  </td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: But if I already have table headers under which header will the select be visible?

Comment: Well in that case you could set your table header for the 2 selects to span 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question then the answer should be...

```
<html>  
<body>  
<table>  
    <tr>
        <td id="t">  
            <div id="select1" >  
                <select>  
                    <option>  
                        John Smith    
                    </option>  
                    <option>  
                        Bill Johnson  
                    </option>  
                    <option>  
                        Mary Jones    
                    </option>  
                </select>   

                <select id="select2" style="display:none">  
                    <option>  
                        CA      
                    </option>  
                    <option>  
                        AZ     
                    </option>    
                    <option>    
                        NV      
                    </option>   
                </select>   
            </div>
        </td>  
        <td><input type="submit" value="Press me!" onclick="doit()"/>  </td>
    </tr>  
</table>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    function doit() {  
        document.getElementById("select2").style.display="inline";  
}   
</script>    
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: But this works fine in my browser.Ok. if @Zaheer's code works fine then you have got your ans :) thanks for try this